# Easy solution to use a SmartCard with a 15" MacBook Pro?

Tags: vpn

I am looking for a simple solution that would enable my MacBook Pro to read smartcards and use them with Cisco AnyConnect VPN solution.

Do you know what cards are supported on OS X Lion?

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine any USB smart card reader should work. Here's one from the Apple site, assuming your card is similar looking to this - http://store.apple.com/us/product/H2312LL/A